# Combinations proving problem

Tags: combinations

Help me prove

$$\binom{n}{r} + \binom{n}{r-1} = \binom{n+1}{r}.$$

Comment: Write down the LHS in terms of factorials and make up into one fraction

Comment: @DavidQuinn : I would prefer a bijective argument. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Suppose you have $n+1$ objects and you want to choose $r$ of them, but one of them is $\mathcal{Special}$.

Break it into cases: either you do pick the $\mathcal{Special}$ object or you don't.  How many ways are there of doing each?

Answer (score 1):

The binomial coefficient ${n}\choose{r}$ is the number of $r$-element subsets of an $n$-element set.  So let's consider an $(n+1)$-element set, say the set contains $n$ pennies and one nickel (or $n$ of one kind of thing and one of a different kind of thing).  How many $r$ element subsets does this set have?  We can choose $r$ pennies, or $r-1$ pennies and one nickel.

Comment: (n+1)!/r!*(n+1-r)!

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}+\frac{n!}{(r-1)!(n-(r-1))!}=\frac{(n-(r-1))\times n!}{r!(n-(r-1))!}+\frac{r\times n!}{r!(n-(r-1))!}=\frac{(n+1)\times n!}{r!(n-(r-1))!}=\frac{(n+1)!}{r!((n+1)-r))!}$

Thus they are equivalent

Comment: Wait i need time to check out...

Comment: $n-(r-1) = n+1-r$.  They are equivalent, as shown by several other methods.

Comment: I'm such a plonker, ive changed it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can start from the definition of the binomial coefficient $\dbinom nr$ as the coefficient of $x^r$ when you develop $(1+x)^n$, and compare the coefficients of $x^r$on both sides of the equation:
$$(1+x)^{n+1}=(1+x)(1+x)^n$$
Comparing, you clearly have $\;\dbinom {n+1}r x^r=1\cdot\dbinom nrx^r+x\cdot\dbinom n{r-1}x^{r-1}.$